# Python opencv Defect detection

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect foreign substances in a round circle using opencv.
However, if the threshold is increased, the area around the circle is distorted, and if the threshold is decreased, foreign matter cannot be detected. Is there a way to detect foreign matter well while maintaining the circle?

```
import cv2 
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def roiSetting():
    img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
    x = 100; y = 10;
    w = 700; h = 600;
    img_roi = img[400:1250,600:1450]        #[colStart:colEnd, rowStart:rowEnd]
    cv2.imwrite("3_roi_img.jpg", img_roi)

    return img_roi  

def imgCvt():
    print("imgCvt in")
    roi_img = roiSetting()
    bgr_img = cv2.cvtColor(roi_img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)           #RGB->BGR convert
    bila_img = cv2.bilateralFilter(bgr_img,9,100,100)           #bilaterafilter apply
    r,g,b=cv2.split(bila_img)                                   #split
    merge_img=cv2.merge((r,g,b))                                #merge
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(merge_img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)       #RGB->GRAY convert
    ret,thresh_img = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU+cv2.THRESH_BINARY) #threshold apply
    equalize_img = cv2.equalizeHist(thresh_img)                     #Histogram equlization
    canny_img = cv2.Canny(equalize_img,250,255)                     #Canny edge
    
    kernel = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8)
    dilate_img = cv2.dilate(canny_img, kernel, iterations = 1)      # img dilate
    new, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilate_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    contours= sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]  #sorting
    print(contours)
    c = contours[0]
    
    mask = np.zeros(roi_img.shape,np.uint8)                             #mask create(roi_img.shape)
    cont_image = cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)   #background remove
    con_gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(cont_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(con_gray_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU+cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    last_img = cv2.bitwise_and(roi_img, roi_img, mask = thresh1)

    kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
    src = cv2.erode(last_img, kernel, iterations = 2)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    rt1, dst1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU+cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    rt1, dst2 = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    _, contour1, _ = cv.findContours(dst2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in contour1:        
        cv2.drawContours(roi_img, [cnt], 0, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_8)
    
    cv2.imshow('cont_roi.jpg', roi_img)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    imgCvt()
```

Comment: Post your input image, please!

Comment: post your input and output